# Comments Vs RDBMS Comments in SQL Developer Data Modeller

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, entity-relationship, erd

I am beginner trying to learn data modelling using SQL Developer Data Modeler.

I am building a Logical Data Model for the first time. My model entities doesn't have many attributes.
However, I would like to see the entity definition as part of the model. When I tried entering my comments, I wasn't able to see them being displayed. When I tried putting in my comments in the RDBMS Comments, I was able to see them.

What is the difference in purpose between the Comments and RDBMS Comments ?  When should comments be used and when should RDBMS Comments be used ?

Kindly throw some light on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comments are for whoever has the model at their disposal. Meaning, if you have the model, you can read the comments.

RDBMS Comments will go into the database as table, view, column comments - so they're for anyone with access to the database. When you generate the object DDL, you'll seem them as COMMENT commands.

I talk about this more [here](https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2013/11/sql-developer-data-modeler-on-notes-comments-and-comments-in-rdbms/)